# The Count and GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT does not group one field and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `user` VARCHAR(15),
  `userid` INTEGER,
  `user_id` INTEGER,
  `ipaddr` VARCHAR(7)
);

INSERT INTO tab
  (`id`, `user`, `userid`, `user_id`, `ipaddr`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Client', '10', '0', '1.1.1.1'),
  ('2', 'admin1', '1', '0', '2.2.2.2'),
  ('3', 'Client', '3', '0', '1.1.1.1'),
  ('4', 'admin2', '5', '0', '3.3.3.3'),
  ('5', 'Client', '12', '0', '4.4.4.4'),
  ('6', 'admin1', '1', '0', '2.2.2.2'),
  ('7', 'Client', '21', '0', '4.4.4.4'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('9', 'Sub-Client 20', '35', '0', '4.4.4.4'),
  ('9', 'Sub-Client 20', '35', '0', '4.4.4.4'),
  ('9', 'Sub-Client 20', '35', '0', '1.1.1.1'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'user1@gmail.com', '30', '0', '7.7.7.7'),
  ('8', 'user1@gmail.com', '30', '0', '7.7.7.7');

SELECT
  COUNT(ipaddr), `ipaddr`, GROUP_CONCAT(`userid` ORDER BY `userid` DESC  ) userid
FROM tab
WHERE `user` = 'Client' OR `user` LIKE 'Sub-Client%' OR `user` LIKE '%@%'
GROUP BY `ipaddr`, `userid`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER By COUNT(ipaddr) DESC
```

This is the result:

```
COUNT(ipaddr) ipaddr userid
2            7.7.7.7 30,30
9            6.6.6.6 25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25
1            4.4.4.4 12
1            4.4.4.4 21
2            4.4.4.4 35,35
1            1.1.1.1 3
1            1.1.1.1 10
1            1.1.1.1 35
```

You may see it live: https://dbfiddle.uk/N8PO_qTN

The issue is:

1. The `userid` in the output has duplicated (like 30 and 25)
2. One IP is repeated multiple times (like 1.1.1.1)

What I'm going to have this as the expected output:

```
COUNT(ipaddr) ipaddr userid
9            6.6.6.6 25
4            4.4.4.4 12, 21, 35
3            1.1.1.1 3, 10, 35
2            7.7.7.7 30
1            4.4.4.4 12
```

Comment: *The userid in the output has duplicated (like 30 and 25)* Nothing in your query provides these duplicates removing. Use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ..)`. *One IP is repeated multiple times (like 1.1.1.1)* GROUP BY expression provides this expression uniqueness but does not provide the uniqueness for a part of this expression. If you want `ipaddr` to be unique in the output then you must remove `userid` from the grouping expression.

Comment: I answered this in your original question

Comment: What is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table`?  Why not have other `UNIQUE` indexes?

Comment: @nbk thanks, I thought it's a different question so I asked a new one because the previous question was answered and solved that problem. Thanks for that comment and the new query

Comment: @RickJames I'll check and tell you. I'm not sure right now.